# jQuery blink(), strike() and bold methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to solve [a question](http://jqexercise.droppages.com/#page_0029_).

I wrote the following code, and it works fine:

```
(function () {
   if($('#target:contains("bold")')) {
      $('#target span:first').css('font-weight','bold');
   } 

   if($('#target:contains("strike")')) {
      $('#target span').eq(1).css('text-decoration','line-through');
   } 

   if($('#target:contains("blink")')) {
      $('#target span:last').css('text-decoration','blink');
   } 
}) ();
```

Their solution is as follows:

```
(function () {
   var target = $('#target');
   var html = target.html();
   html = html.replace('blink',"$&".blink());
   html = html.replace('bold',"$&".bold());
   html = html.replace('strike',"$&".strike());
   target.html(html);
}) ();
```

I have the following questions:

1. I do not understand what is `"$&"` in `"$&".blink()`, `"$&".bold()` and `"$&".strike()`,
2. Are `blink`, `bold` and `strike` jQuery UI methods?

Comment: i haven't personally seen that.

Comment: jquery objects are always truthy so your if checks are always true.

Comment: @epascarello That was really helpful. So, what is the use of if statements if they are always going to return true.

Comment: if statements are find, what is in it is wrong. Should be checking the length of the object to see if jQuery found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are not jQuery methods. Everything in jQuery is either a function that of the form `$.funcName()` or a method that operates on a jQuery object, e.g. `$(something).methodName()`.

These are regular Javascript methods of the `String` class: [`String.prototype.blink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/blink)
, [`String.prototype.bold`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold), [`String.prototype.strike`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike). They just wrap their argument with the appropriate HTML element. However, they have been deprecated, because CSS is preferred these days rather than the old tags like `<blink>`, so you shouldn't use them.

`"$&"` is a feature of the `.replace()` method, it's automatically replaced with the original matching element. It's mostly useful when using a regular expression, since you don't know the exact string that will match the pattern.

Your solution to the problem doesn't look like it will work properly. It assumes that each word is in its own span, and also that `bold` is in the first span, `strike` is in the second span, and `blink` is in the third span. The objective of the exercise is to find the words wherever they are in the DIV, and put the appropriate style around just that word.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript `replace()` method uses regular expressions. The `$&` syntax is shorthand for the matched expression; so it will represent `blink`, `bold`, and `strike` respectively.

As [@Daniel A. White mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386522/3025856), `blink()`, `bold()`, and `strike()` are deprecated methods from `string.prototype` for wrapping the source string in markup. The exact markup used will vary by browser; for instance, one may return `<b>bold</b>`, another `<strong>bold</strong>` and yet another `<span style="font-weight: bold">bold</span>`.

For what it's worth, while [@Barmr's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386543/3025856) is shorter, I find yours more elegant in that it's easy to understand, consistent in its results, and standards-based. That said, [@Barmar raises valid concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30386543/3025856) regarding the assumptions it makes and, therefore, its usefulness in a general context.

Answer (score 0):

Those are deprecated methods for wrapping a string in a certain element.

`String.prototype.blink` reveals it to be a native method.

You can view those here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/blink
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/bold
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/strike